# Do I need to use the article with "primavera"?

Tags: traducción, artículos

How must one translate "spring" as in the season?

Is it 'primavera' or rather '**la** primavera'? As we don't say '**the** spring" in English, but "spring", I guess it must be 'primavera' (just like that) in Spanish as well?

Sometimes I see *primaveral* but I guess that's an adjective.

Comment: It would help if you gave us context and a sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it is a matter of personal preferences and the meaning of the sentence since both **primavera** and **la primavera** are correct.  In some contexts you need the article and in others you don't.

Also, one sounds better than the other in some contexts.

See this sentence

> I'll be traveling to Europe **this spring** = Viajaré a Europa **esta primavera**

There you can not use "la", but if we change the sentence to

> I'll be traveling to Europe **in [the] spring** = Viajaré a Europa en **(la) primavera**

then you can use "la" if you prefer but it will be right either way.

In the following sentence you have to use "la"

> I traveled to Europe last spring = Viajé a Europa **la primavera** pasada

In the following example it sounds better if you use "la".

> I love **spring** = Me gusta **la primavera**

other example where both are ok is:

> Plants bloom in [the] spring = Las plantas florecen en (la) primavera

So for a good translation you have to check the preposition used in English. For example if you have "this" you don't use "la", with "on" you could choose if you want to use "la" but with "last, next" you have to include "la". Prepositions are difficult in all languages but you get use to them as you hear them more and more.